# unable to copy multiple file to multiple destinations in data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am learning ADF and below issue occurred while practicing. I have json file which contains path of files to be copied. This json file is stored in azure data lake. I am trying to read json file using web activity and using this output as input to foreach activity. In my foreach activity I have used copy activity which copies files.

As I know, foreach activity requires input as array and I am unable to parse the output of web activity and getting error message

*The execution of template action 'MainForEach1' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@activity('web').output.Response' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.*

can somebody please advice how can I proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) and pass the output to ForEach activity. Below is the repro with the sample JSON file.

[image]

lookup output:

[image]

ForEach activity:

[image]